# getView never called Baseadapter

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter

searched the most common similar Topics but nothing helped.

```
public class NewCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context activityContext;
    LayoutInflater myInflater;
    Drawable[] myDrawableArray;
    String[] myLabelArray;
    String[] myABCArray;
    int position = 0;
    ImageView myImg;
    TextView myLabelTextView;
    TextView myABCTextView;

    public NewCustomAdapter(Context context) {

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.activityContext = context;
        myInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("getcount","true  " + position);
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder {

        ImageView img;
        TextView tv;
        TextView abc;

        public Holder(ImageView img, TextView tv, TextView abc) {

            this.img = img;
            this.tv = tv;
            this.abc = abc;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("getView","true");
        if(convertView == null) {

            convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.customadapter_view_layout_medium, null);
            myImg = (ImageView)     convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_layout_normal_portrait_sizemedium);
            myLabelTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_label_layout_normal_portrait_sizemedium);
            myABCTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_abc_layout_normal_portrait_sizemedium);
            convertView.setTag(new Holder(myImg,myLabelTextView, myABCTextView));
        } else {

            Holder holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
            myImg = holder.img;
            myLabelTextView = holder.tv;
            myABCTextView = holder.abc;
        }
        myImg.setImageDrawable(myDrawableArray[position]);
        myLabelTextView.setText(myLabelArray[position]);
        myABCTextView.setText(myABCArray[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

    public void updateGridView(Drawable[] myDrawableArray_, String[] myLabelArray_, String[] myABCArray_, int position_) {

        this.myDrawableArray = myDrawableArray_;
        this.myLabelArray = myLabelArray_;
        this.myABCArray = myABCArray_;
        this.position = position_;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

It's a normal BaseAdapter which gets update from my backgroundThread. My BackgroundThread calls

```
updateGridView(...)
```

method. Method is called as wanted. getCount is also called everytime i call updateGridView.. so that works as well. Only Problem is. GridView doesn't inflate. getView is never called.

in my AsyncTask i set correctly on UIThread(onPreExecute()):

```
gv = (GridView) myActivityView.findViewById(R.id.gv1);
myCustomAdapter = new NewCustomAdapter(myActivityContext);
gv.setAdapter(myCustomAdapter);
```

No Errors, getView is just never called, that's why gridview is never inflated... Any help is appreciated.

Comment: there are many issue in your code 
i think must go through the proper tutorial of base adapter.

getView is called when there is any list items 

here no list pass to the contructor of your CustomAdapter

Comment: @DanialHussain that sounds good or bad, however. So my Problem seems to be that i pass an Array and not a List? And that's why he never calls the getView..

Comment: myCustomAdapter = new NewCustomAdapter(myActivityContext); 

there is issue

Comment: see the given link how they override the constructor.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: @DanialHussain i know this tutorial but he doesn't use a simple BaseAdapter, he uses ArrayAdapter. If i got multiple Arrays with different Types, isn't it better to use an ArrayAdapter?

Comment: yes create a interface inwhich you must define your functions 
and all your objects must implement that interface.
and override those methods and in array adapter pass that base interface.

Comment: interface BaseObject{ void getTitle(); }

class sampleObject implements BaseObject{
 override
 void getTitle{}
}

Comment: the pass public class NewCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BaseObject> {}

Comment: @Danial Hussain can you provide me a code example as an answere. If it works i will set your answere as accepted. Would be really nice !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20608498/3322203  see this link example

Comment: use array adapter with custom objects.
see both link and enjoy happy programmming

Answer (score 2):

getCount() return size of list data and also properly implement [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) design pattern for ListView performance :

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return myDrawableArray.length;
}
```

**Example :**

```
public class NewCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    Drawable[] myDrawableArray;
    String[] myLabelArray;
    String[] myABCArray;
    int position;
    public NewCustomAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return myDrawableArray.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return myDrawableArray[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder {
        ImageView img;
        TextView tv;
        TextView abc;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder holder;
        if(convertView == null) {
            holder = new Holder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.customadapter_view_layout_medium, null);
            holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_layout_normal_portrait_sizemedium);
            holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_label_layout_normal_portrait_sizemedium);
            holder.abc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_abc_layout_normal_portrait_sizemedium);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.img.setImageDrawable(myDrawableArray[position]);
        holder.tv.setText(myLabelArray[position]);
        holder.abc.setText(myABCArray[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

    public void updateGridView(Drawable[] myDrawableArray_, String[] myLabelArray_, String[] myABCArray_, int position_) {
        this.myDrawableArray = myDrawableArray_;
        this.myLabelArray = myLabelArray_;
        this.myABCArray = myABCArray_;
        this.position = position_;

        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your respone. In my case this is not possible. I Need to return the Position and not the length of my Array. Anyway, short time ago i was able to get it started with Position as well. No Need to return the Array.length. I think the Problem is that i pass an Array and not an List. Do you think the same??

Comment: Thank you for your time Haresh Chhelana. But i can't use Array.length because my Array is fixed sized from the beginning due to Performance issues. Therefore my Array is for example 300 Units big but i only Need 200 of them. The rest of them is null. If i would set Array.length.. then my GridView would be scollable to the whole Array(where last 50 or 100 "Units" are null).

Comment: Then which is same size array i mean myLabelArray or myABCArray ?

Comment: They are all 300 "Long". But i'm using only about 200. But my Problem is that at the beginning i don't know how much i will use. That's why i set them to 300..

Comment: When you know actual size again initialize with exact data size.

Answer (score 1):

`getView` is called if `getCount` returns something `!= 0`,

Comment: Thank you for your Response. Please take a closer look at my updateGridView method. Where i set Position to a number higher than 0. So after i notify the BaseAdapter with a higher Position getView would Need to be called... it never stays 0! Just at the very beginning.. In other words, i also tried Setting Position at the beginning to 1, same issue appears..so it has nothing to do with the Position starts with 0

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the total count in getCount method

Since your first position is 0 your getCount method returns 0 and the adapter thinks that there are no elements to be displayed in the list.

Comment: Thank you for your Response. Please take a closer look at my updateGridView method. Where i set Position to a number higher than 0. So after i notify the BaseAdapter with a higher Position getView would Need to be called... it never stays 0! Just at the very beginning.. In other words, i also tried Setting Position at the beginning to 1, same issue appears..so it has nothing to do with the Position starts with 0

Comment: I think the problem is that you are trying to update the UI in the BackGround Thread since you are calling that updateGridView method from the background thread, try to execute it in the UIThread and maybe it will work

Comment: Tried it, same issue. I think the Problem is, that i don't pass a List but an Array. Is this possible? If so, how could i Setup an Adapter passing my Arrays?

Comment: That's never a problem man, you can pass an array too, there's no problem in that, I think you should check some reference codes implementing grid view on the internet, it's highly likely that you are forgetting some basic initialization or something like that

Comment: You sure? Man this issue is getting me down... In the comments below my question Danial Hussain says that i Need to pass a list instead of an Array... so what's true now?

Comment: I have passed an array several times and displayed lists in my apps, all i can say is, try making the most basic list and find it out yourself :)

Comment: I did right now. Problem stays the same. So you should be right. Maybe we can go in Chat an walk trough my asynctask? it's not really Long.. Maybe i'm Setting something wrong?

Comment: You don't yet have enough reputation to chat

Comment: i will try to put a new question since the Problem is probably at the Setup. Can you provide any tutorial where someone tries to Setup a gridview with Adapter in a seperate thread? Would be relly nice

Comment: That's the problem i am pointing out since the very beginning you can't simply update the UI from Non-UIThread, check out the link below, it will inform you about all the ways to update the UI:
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/05/painless-threading.html